# How does python know when to return a generator?

Tags: python, generator

When I put a `yield` in function body, obviously. But that's not what I'm trying to ask. Given two simple functions in an interactive interpreter:

```
def myGenerator():
    yield 42

def myFunction():
    return 42
```

When I execute both I see:

```
>>> myGenerator()
<generator object myGenerator at 0xb7bf511c>
>>> myFunction()
42
```

But If inspect the `myGenerator` and `myFunction` objects, I don't see anything really different:

```
for attr in dir(myFunction):
    print(attr, getattr(myFunction, attr)
```

produces stuff that looks the same as `myGenerator`. Is there some magic bit hidden in the bowels of the function object, that the interpreter branches off of to discern whether to wrap the function invocation as a generator? Or is it done more decorator style, where the presence of the yield keyword caused the object bound as `'myGenerator'` to be wrapped in some generator magic? Or something else...?

Comment: answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"A generator function is an ordinary function object in all respects, but has the new CO_GENERATOR flag set in the code object's co_flags member."

From the PEP http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/

```
 >>> generator_fn.__code__.co_flags
 >>> 99
 >>> normal_fn.__code__.co_flags
 >>> 67
```